# Looking to use Gulp to create individual distributions of standalone HTML files

Tags: node.js, gulp

Basically I'm looking for a Gulp plugin to turn a directory like this:

```
/app
     - htmlfile1.html
     - htmlfile2.html
     - htmlfile3.html
     - /css
          -cssmain.css
     -/js
          -global.js
```

And turn that into this:

```
/dist
     -/htmlfile1
          - htmlfile1.html
          - /css
               -cssmain.css
          -/js
               -global.js
     - /htmlfile2
          - htmlfile2.html
          - /css
               -cssmain.css
          -/js
               -global.js
     - /htmlfile3
          - htmlfile3.html
          - /css
               -cssmain.css
          -/js
               -global.js
```

Any thoughts on how to do accomplish a build system like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code allows `common` files to be added to every page distribution as well as unique dependencies defined as an array in the `pages` object.

The following Gulp file relies on [gulp-foreach](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-foreach), [parse-filepath](https://www.npmjs.org/package/parse-filepath), and [event-stream](https://www.npmjs.org/package/event-stream): `npm install gulp gulp-foreach parse-filepath event-stream --save-dev`

`gulpfile.js`:

```
// Command:
// npm install gulp gulp-foreach parse-filepath event-stream --save-dev

// Include gulp
var gulp = require('gulp');

var foreach = require('gulp-foreach'); // https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-foreach
var parsePath = require('parse-filepath'); // https://www.npmjs.org/package/parse-filepath
var es = require('event-stream'); // https://www.npmjs.org/package/event-stream

// The pages that each make a distribution
// Unique dependencies are defined as an array value for each page.
var pages = {
    './app/htmlfile1.html': [
        './app/images/1.png',
        './app/images/1-another.png',
    ],
    './app/htmlfile2.html': [],
    './app/htmlfile3.html': []
};

// Files added to each page distribution
var common = [
    './app/css/cssmain.css',
    './app/js/global.js',
];

function makeDistributionStream(page)
{
    var gulpStream = gulp.src(page)
        .pipe(foreach(function(stream, file) {
            var pathParts = parsePath(file.path);
            // Assemble the distribution path
            var destinationPath = './dist/' + pathParts.name + '/';

            // Pipe the html into the distribution folder
            stream.pipe(gulp.dest(destinationPath));

            // Move all of the unique and common files into the distibution
            var uniqueDependencies = pages[page];
            // Merge the common files to the unique ones
            var distFiles = uniqueDependencies.concat(common);
            gulp.src(distFiles, {base: './app/'})
                .pipe(gulp.dest(destinationPath));
        }));

    return gulpStream;
}

// Assemble the distribution directories for each page
gulp.task('make-distributions', function() {
    var mergedStream = null;
    for(var page in pages)
    {
        var stream = makeDistributionStream(page);

        // Merge the streams, if there is already one
        if(mergedStream)
        {
            mergedStream = es.merge(mergedStream, stream);
        }
        // Otherwise, just make it this one
        else
        {
            mergedStream = stream;
        }
    }

    return mergedStream;
});

// Rerun the task when a file changes
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    // If the html pages change, re-make the distributions
    gulp.watch(Object.keys(pages), ['make-distributions']);
});

// Default Task
gulp.task('default', ['make-distributions', 'watch']);
```

Comment: Interesting use for for-each, what about for images or script's unique to a page?

Comment: @Droidnoid The code now accommodates unique dependencies for each distribution.

Comment: Nice!  Marking as answered, any way to scan the html page's resources and pull those it rather than an array?